# What is the best way to rotate multiple URLs in wordpress when running an ad campaign?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to rotate two or more landing pages through one URL. The website I buy traffic from only allows one URL per ad. I could create more ads with each URL but that will get too repetitive.

I am running on wordpress and using the woocommerce plugin for ecommerce. I have tried looking for a plugin that would generate a URL that could rotate my landing pages, but unfortunately I could not find any that would do exactly that. I have however, found a script that already does this, but it's not through wordpress and the solution can get chaotic.

```
<?php
$k = $_GET['sub'];

$aff[] = 'url1';
$aff[] = 'url2';
$aff[] = 'url3';


srand ((double) microtime() * 1000000);
$random_number = rand(0,count($aff)-1);

$lol = ($aff[$random_number]);
$lal = $lol.$k;

header("Location: $lal");
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy ways to use the pulgin for setup the Ad campaign, you can go through step for WordPress Ad Manager & AdSense Ads – Ad Inserter Plugin.

Follow the Wordpress plugin url - [WordPress Ad Manager & AdSense Ads – Ad Inserter Plugin.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ad-inserter/)

Comment: First of all thanks for taking the time to answer.From what I see, the plugin has a/b testing feature to test on page. What I'm looking for is the entire web page itself to be rotated. I want it where I would have a redirect URL (site.com / redirect.php) and then it would randomly select one page out of a list to go to.